# Android Google ML Vision Barcode Scanner Limitations

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I have been working with the google ML kit for the past couple of days and have stumbled upon some problems.
Specifically when I use their `BarcodeScanner` I am getting limited by only getting up-to 10 barcodes from the screen or an image at a time.

This is a part of my implementation:

`barcodeDetector = BarcodeScanning.getClient()`

```
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        if (shouldScanBarcode) { // Check the scanning flag before initiating barcode detection
            val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
            if (mediaImage != null) {
                val rotationDegrees = imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees

                // Create an InputImage object from the ImageProxy
                val inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotationDegrees)

                // Process the image with the barcode detector
                barcodeDetector.process(inputImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                        // 'barcodes' contains the list of detected barcodes

                        // Perform any necessary processing on the 'barcodes' list
                        // For example, you can loop through the list and extract information from each barcode

                        // Notify your activity or UI with the detected barcodes
                        println("Detected ${barcodes.size} barcodes")
                        Toast.makeText(scannerActivity, "Detected ${barcodes.size} barcodes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        scannerActivity.onBarcodesDetected(barcodes)
                        toggleBarcodeScanning(false)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        // Handle any errors that occurred during barcode detection
                        toggleBarcodeScanning(false)
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        // Close the imageProxy after processing is complete
                        toggleBarcodeScanning(false)
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
            } else {
                // Close the imageProxy if the media image is null
                toggleBarcodeScanning(false)
                imageProxy.close()
            }
        } else {
            // Close the imageProxy if barcode scanning is not needed
            toggleBarcodeScanning(false)
            imageProxy.close()
        }
    }
```

Here in my onSuccessListener I am **always** getting a maximum of 10 barcodes.
I have also checked the MLKit Vision Demo application created by Google and debugged their code, and I can also see that the returned data consists of maximum of 10 barcodes.

The question is: Can this limitation be removed or at least increased to a point where the barcode scanner would be more useful. What is currently provided does not seem enough.

PS. I also have tried the object recognition client and it has a limitation of 5 objects. So probably there is some way to increase that number.